# Verwenden von „dieser“ für undefinierte Objekte

Tags: article, demonstrative-pronoun, definiteness

Im Englischen kann man „**this**“ für die Objekte/Personen verwenden, die bisher nicht erwähnt wurden, um diese Objekte/Personen besonders zu betonen, zum Beispiel:

> Yesterday I was in a bus and there was **this** young guy. He was so loud.
>
> I was in a bar and saw **this** pretty waitress. I‘ve never seen such a beautiful woman before.

Kann man sowas auch auf Deutsch 1 zu 1 übertragen?

> Gestern war ich in einem Bus und da war **dieser** junge Mann. Er war so laut.
>
> Ich war in einer Bar und sah **diese** hübsche Kellnerin. Ich habe noch nie so eine schöne Frau gesehen.

In beiden Fällen geht es um eine neue Person, über die vorher nicht gesprochen wurde.

Comment: Wie bereits geantwortet, ist dieser Gebrauch jetzt üblich. Nicht erwähnt wurde, dass die deutsche Entsprechung voher lautete "...so ein junger Mann".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deutsch ist eine lebende Sprache, und wie alles das lebt, verändert sie sich. Als ich noch ein Kind war (geboren 1965) wäre niemand auf die Idee gekommen, das Demonstrativpronomen *»dies«* und seine Beugungsformen so zu verwenden, wie es in der Frage vorgeschlagen wurde.

Heute, ein halbes Jahrhundert später, ist diese Verwendungsform durchaus bereits einigermaßen verbreitet, auch wenn sie noch immer ein wenig seltsam klingt. Dass diese Verwendungsform überhaupt Eingang in die deutsche Sprache gefunden hat, wird, wie ich vermute, auf den Einfluss der englischen Sprache zurückzuführen sein.

Das Problem bei *»dies«* in diesem Kontext ist seine [Definitheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitheit_(Linguistik)) (auf Deutsch: *Bestimmtheit*). Die Definitheit ist eine grammatische Kategorie, die den Unterschied zwischen *definit* (*bestimmt*) und *indefinit* (*unbestimmt*) ausmacht, z.B. bei Artikeln:

- definit (bestimmt): der, die, das, des, dem, den
- indefinit (unbestimmt): ein, eine, eines, einer, einem, einen

Das Demonstrativpronomen *»dies«* (*dieser, diese, dieses, diesen, diesem*) ist ein definites Pronomen, es verweist also auf ein ganz bestimmtes Ding oder auf eine ganz bestimmte Person. Das trifft übrigens auf alle deutschen Demonstrativpronomen zu (*jener, jene, jenes, der, derer, deren, ...*).

Wenn man aber jemandem davon erzählt, dass man im Bus **einen** (nicht: <del>den</del>!) jungen Mann mit besonderen Eigenschaften gesehen hat, dann ist dieser junge Mann indefinit:

- Richtig (indefinit):

> Ich habe im Bus **einen** jungen Mann gesehen. Er war sehr laut.
> In der Bar war **eine** hübsche Kellnerin. Sie war sehr schön.

- Falsch (definit):

> Ich habe im Bus **den** jungen Mann gesehen. Er war sehr laut.
> In der Bar war **die** hübsche Kellnerin. Sie war sehr schön.

Warum muss man hier die indefinite Form verwenden?
Das muss man, weil die Person unbekannt ist. Es ist eine von vielen. Es ist nicht ein ganz bestimmter junger Mann, den der Sprecher schon vorher gekannt hat, und es ist nicht eine ganz bestimmte Kellnerin, sondern irgend ein Mann und irgend eine Frau. Dass diese Personen durch besondere Eigenschaften aufgefallen sind, macht sie nicht zu bestimmten Personen, jedenfalls nicht in der deutschen Grammatik.

Wie schon erwähnt sind deutsche Demonstrativpronomen immer definit, sie entsprechen in ihrer Definitheit also den bestimmten Artikeln. Daher kann man sie (eigentlich) nur in Situationen verwenden, in denen auch ein definiter Artikel angebracht wäre:

- definit, korrekte Verwendung des Demonstrativpronomens:

  > Kannst du dich an den gelben Hut erinnern, den mir Barbara bei der Party letzte Woche geschenkt hat? Ludwig hat mir heute gesagt, dass er mir **diesen** Hut abkaufen möchte.
- indefinit, das Demonstrativpronomen wird falsch verwendet:

  > Wie du weißt, sammle ich Hüte. Ich habe Hüte in allen Größen, Formen und Farben. Ludwig hat mir heute gesagt, dass er mir **diesen** Hut abkaufen möchte. Es ist der gelbe, den mir Barbara bei der Party letzte Woche geschenkt hat.
- indefinit, mit unbestimmten Artikel anstelle eines Demonstrativpronomens (korrekt):

  > Wie du weißt, sammle ich Hüte. Ich habe Hüte in allen Größen, Formen und Farben. Ludwig hat mir heute gesagt, dass er mir **einen** Hut abkaufen möchte. Es ist der gelbe, den mir Barbara bei der Party letzte Woche geschenkt hat.

**Aber:**

- korrekt:

  > Wie du weißt, sammle ich Hüte. Ich habe Hüte in allen Größen, Formen und Farben. Ludwig hat mir heute gesagt, dass er mir **diesen** Hut abkaufen möchte, den ich hier in der Hand halte.
- auch korrekt:

  > Wie du weißt, sammle ich Hüte. Ich habe Hüte in allen Größen, Formen und Farben. Ludwig hat mir heute gesagt, dass er mir **jenen** Hut abkaufen möchte, den mir Barbara bei der Party letzte Woche geschenkt hat.

Hier ist die Verwendung eines definiten Demonstrativpronomens korrekt, weil das referenzierte Objekt (der Hut) in einem Relativsatz genau bestimmt wird. Daher sind auch diese Formulierungen korrekt:

> Gestern war ich in einem Bus und da war **dieser** junge Mann, der so laut war.
> Ich war in einer Bar und sah **diese** hübsche Kellnerin, die schöner war als alle anderen Frauen, die ich je gesehen habe.

Hier sind der Mann und die Kellnerin durch den Relativsatz näher bestimmt, weswegen die Verwendung eines Demonstrativpronomens erlaubt ist. Wenn es weder eine einführende nähere Beschreibung noch einen Relativsatz gibt, ist ein Objekt, das erstmals in der Erzählung auftaucht, zunächst unbestimmt und verträgt sich nicht mit einem Demonstrativpronomen.

Comment: Sehr gute Antwort, aber in einem Detail muss ich doch widersprechen. Ob der junge dem Sprecher bekannt oder unbekannt ist, ist unerheblich. Wichtig ist, ob er zuletzt sprachlich isoliert wurde. Hier wird er erst als der ungewöhnlich laute identifiziert, danach kann auf ihn mit "dieser" verwiesen werden.

Comment: Danke für diese detaillierte Antwort!

Comment: @userunknown Da muss ich widersprechen. Durch eine besondere Betonung von "dies(er)" kann es eingesetzt werden, auch wenn das Objekt vorher nicht eingeführt wurde. z.B. "In der Stadt hat jetzt diese neue Bar eröffnet und die ist echt gut!" wäre völlig in Ordnung, auch wenn vorher nicht einmal über eine Bar die Rede war.

Comment: Um die gleiche Wirkung dieses englischen "this" zu erzielen, könnte man "so ein" statt das neumodisch und scheinbar falsche "dies" verwenden? Also: In der Bar war so eine hübsche Kellnerin. Sie war sehr schön.

Comment: @userunknown: Ja, da muss ich dir Recht geben.

Comment: @Sentry: Das steht nicht im Widerspruch zum Kommentar von *user unknown.* In einer konservativen Interpretation der deutschen Grammatik ist die hier diskutierte Verwendung eines Demonstrativpronomens auch dann inkorrekt, wenn es betont wird, denn die konservative Grammatik berücksichtigt solche Betonungen gar nicht. Sie fokussiert sich (leider!) so gut wie ausschließlich auf geschriebene Sprache, in der Wortbetonungen schlichtweg nicht existieren. Dem geschriebenen Deutsch fehlt also eine ganze Dimension. Ebenso fehlen Mimik und Gestik, die in vielen Sprachen aber eine bedeutende Rolle spielen

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Richtig, ich habe wohl im Eifer des Gefechts den Kommentar falsch gelesen. Ich stimme dir und user unknown völlig zu